# In sentences matrices too close to other lines

Tags: matrices, line-spacing

In my tex line spaces are 1.5 but if I write matrices in a sentence, these matrices are closer to lines than normal. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt that one should typeset those 'vectors' inline! Perhaps you should use the transposed vector for inline representation and restrict the vertical one for the display math

Comment: as addendum to Christian Hupfer comment: as `$[b_1\, b_2\,\dotsm\, b_k]^T$` (anticipated, that in preamble you have `\usepackage{amsmath}`).

Comment: @Zarko: I left that as an exercise to the O.P ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It really makes no sense to typeset column matrices inline, you should use a horizontal layout or use display math, however if you really do want to do this, the spacing used when things are too big to fit in `\baselineskip` spacing is `\lineskip` so while increasing the baselineskip you might also want to increase `\lineskip` up from its usual value of 1pt to, say, 3pt.

Answer (score 4):

As [David writes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346757/15874), you shouldn't use column matrices in inline text.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\spc{1ex}

\begin{document}

\section*{First option}
Something $b' = \begin{bmatrix}b_{1} & b_{2} & \cdots & b_{k}\end{bmatrix}_{k+1}$ and $x' = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} & x_{2} & \cdots & x_{t}\end{bmatrix}_{t+1}$ something.

\section*{Second option}
Something
\begin{equation*}
  b' = \begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\[\spc] b_{2}\\[\spc] \vdots\\[\spc] b_{k}\end{bmatrix}_{k+1}
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  x' = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\[\spc] x_{2}\\[\spc] \vdots\\[\spc] b_{t}\end{bmatrix}_{t+1}
\end{equation*}
something.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]